# Using multiple PHP files to connect and submit data to MSSQL database

Tags: php

I am working on a project where user input is sent back to a SQL database. I have 3 PHP files: 1 - creates a connection with the db. 2 - has a function submitAnswers() that creates a stmt and executes it. 3 - index page that calls the function to submit the data. I get this error when I run it:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_prepare. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_prepare. ) )

When I run all of this code from one file, it works - connects to my db and writes to it. I assume this is something to do with me not knowing how to use require_once and/or include

This is the code for each file.

> db.inc.php

```
<?php


$serverName = "localhost\\sqlexpress";  

/* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */  
$uid = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\uid.txt");  
$pwd = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\pwd.txt");  
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,  
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,  
                     "Database"=>"mydb");  

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

if( $conn === false )  
{  
    echo "Unable to connect.</br>";  
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
```

> functions.inc.php

```
<?php

function submitAnswers(){

$sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[testtable] (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array("John", "Doe");
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn,  $sql, $params);
   
if($stmt)
{
    echo "Statement prepared.\n";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error in executing statement.\n";
    
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
/* Execute the statement. Display any errors that occur. */  
if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt))  
{  
      echo "Statement executed.\n";  
}  
else  
{  
     echo "Error in executing statement.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  
header("location: success.php");
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
exit();

}
```

> index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'db.inc.php';
require_once 'functions.inc.php';

submitAnswers();
```

Like I said, the reason I have this split in three files is because I have been told this is a good practice.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: Add this to the top of the main script, will show more errors. 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: It may have a problem findings the file files. Depending on php was set up it might not look in the current dir. `require_once __DIR__.'/db.inc.php';` `__DIR__` is a [magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Inside `submitAnswers()`, what is `$conn` supposed to be? Where is it supposed to be coming from? Is PHP smart enough to figure this out? (Hint: the last answer is "no.")

Comment: @miken32 yes, I've tried wrapping the db connection code in a function and return $conn but that didn't work either.